# Why does one website think I'm offline when I'm not?

Tags: dns, browser, website

This started happening soon after the Dyn DDoS attack of Oct 21, 2016.  Whenever I go to https://www.smashingmagazine.com/ it always shows me a special page for offline, titled "Smashing Magazine Offline" and explaining "You might not have a proper connection, but it doesn’t mean that you can’t read articles on Smashing Magazine. We use service workers to cache some assets and pages, so you can access the site faster, even if you are offline."

(EDIT) Sometimes before the "Offline" page appears, chromium will show an error page, stating it's ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN

So far, I haven't found any other sites which do this.  All other sites - news, weather, politics, all stack exchange sites, youtube, engineering trade rags, ad-infested click bait sites, whatever - all work fine. Except Smashing.  The problem occurs for Firefox and Chromium.  Both browsers have been closed completely and reopened, multiple windows with multiple tabs.

Is there something stuck in a cache on my machine? Funny business at my ISP?  Is it trouble at Smashing's end?  How to investigate this?  How to fix this, hopefully in an easy and educational way?

(EDIT) In Firefox with its debugger, I find:

```
Error loading this URL: Could not load the source for https://www.smashingmagazine.com/.
Error: Failed to fetch https://www.smashingmagazine.com/. Code 2153390067.
Stack: mainThreadFetch/onResponse@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://devtools/shared/DevToolsUtils.js:418:23
NetUtil_asyncFetch/<.onStopRequest@resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm:128:17
Line: 418, column: 23
```

Comment: Try changing DNS server, see if that works. I recommend using google or opendns.

Comment: Firebug headers etc would be a start.

Comment: An anonymous edit was proposed that I'll assume was by you.  You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  I'll go ahead and vote to approve it, but if it was not your edit, you will need to roll it back.

Comment: Odd. I'm logged in, sometimes I'm not.  Maybe it's a side effect of screwing around with stuff trying to fix this.  Yes, it's my edit.